# How to make a button that can change background color of a doucment?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a button that when it's clicked ,the background color of my webpage changes. I have tried already with Javascript & Css but no success! Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test
        </title>
        <style>
        .bgcolor1{
            background-color:black;
        }
        .bgcolor2{
            background-color:grey;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="bgcolor1">
        <button onclick="this.className = 'bgcolor2'">Change COLOUR</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see when the user click on the button it should change the class to "bgcolor2" so the background color would be grey but it just changes the background color of the button to grey & not the document!
So how can I change the background color of document with css or js or what's the problem with this code? thx ...

Comment: `document.body.className = 'bgcolor2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onclick="document.body.className = 'bgcolor2'">Change COLOUR</button>
```

`this` refers to the button and not the body. `document.body.className = 'bgcolor2';`

Answer (score 0):

Simply target `document.body.className` instead of `this`; in this scenario, `this` is a reference to the button itself. Make your `onclick` attribute as below

```
onclick="document.body.className='myCustomBGColor'"
```

where `myCustomBGColor` is a CSS class.

Here's your final working fiddle

```css
        .bgcolor1{
            background-color:black;
        }
        .bgcolor2{
            background-color:grey;
        }
```

```html
<body class="bgcolor1">
        <button onclick="document.body.className = 'bgcolor2'">Change COLOUR</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `document.body` instead of `this`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test
        </title>
        <style>
        .bgcolor1{
            background-color:black;
        }
        .bgcolor2{
            background-color:grey;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="bgcolor1">
        <button onclick="document.body.className = 'bgcolor2'">Change COLOUR</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction(){
    document.body.className = 'bgcolor';
}
```

**CSS**

```
.bgcolor{
    background:red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lytujmm/)